# Как создать метод объекта, если объект создается при помощи функции конструктора?

Tags: javascript, классы

Пытаюсь создать метод **test** объекта **MyObject** таким образом:

```
<script>
    function MyObject(){
        function test(){};
    };

    var my = new MyObject();

    my.test();
</script>
```

В консоль валится ошибка:

> TypeError: my.test is not a function

не пойму что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания метода в конструкторе, нужно добавить этот метод в `this`

```
function MyObject(){
    this.test = function test(){};
};

var my = new MyObject();

my.test();
```

Либо, если использовать ES2015

```
class MyObject{
    test(){};
};

var my = new MyObject();

my.test();
```

```js
function MyObject(){
    this.test = function test(){
      document.write('test from constructor','<br/>');
    };
};

var my = new MyObject();

my.test();


class MyObject2015{
    test(){
      document.write('ES2015: test from constructor','<br/>');
    };
};

var my = new MyObject2015();

my.test();
```

Comment: спасибо выручил.

Comment: es6 методы в прототип пишет, а не в инстенс конструктора. Так же стоит заметить что js это язык построенный на прототипах и по этому более разумно методы писать именно в прототип.

Comment: ```
var MyObject = function () {
    function MyObject() {
        _classCallCheck(this, MyObject);
    }
    MyObject.prototype.test = function test() {
    };
    return MyObject;
}();
```

Comment: Так Ваш класс скомпилируется в es5.

Comment: @vas, ну и что?:) я не говорил что методы не попадут в прототип

Comment: @vas, кроме того, в некоторых случаях нельзя использовать прототип, так что выражение: _более разумно методы писать именно в прототип._ в корне не верно

Comment: поддержу @Grundy когда я поместил метод в прототип мой код выругался словами **ошибка вызвана рекурсия**

Comment: В большинстве случаев все-таки стоит использовать прототип для определения методов(не говоря о экзотических случаях с приватными свойствами). Причины две: меньше памяти, проще наследоваться.

Answer (score 5):

На всякий случай обращу ваше внимание на тот факт, что создавать методы в конструкторе неэффективно с точки зрения памяти. Фактически, в первом примере из ответа **@Grundy** при создании *каждого* нового объекта `MyObject` создается *новая* функция `test`. В большинстве случаев, это является нежелательным эффектом (использование конструктора, как замыкания я специально здесь не рассматриваю).

Кроме того, создавая методы в конструкторе, вы усложняете механизм наследования.

Как следствие, в большинстве случаев правильнее привязывать методы к *прототипу* создаваемого объекта, а именно:

```
var MyObject = function(foo) {
    // Инициализация свойств, уникальных для каждого ЭКЗЕМПЛЯРА MyObject.
    this.foo = foo;
};

MyObject.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
};

var my = new MyObject('test');
my.test(); // Выведет "test"
```